# Django href pass multiple parameters to function

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, href, django-urls

I want to pass two parameters from an HTML page throw href to a function
first the parameter are:
HTML page,

```
{{object.id}}
.
.
 {% for item in model_items %}
<td>{{item.ID}}</td>
<td class="p-1 mb-1 text-dark">
<a href="{% url 'Up_Items' item.id {{object.id}} %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Add Item</a></td>
```

and the second thing is the urls.py;

```
 path('Up_Items/<int:id_itm,id_itm2>/', views.ADD_item, name='Up_Items'),
```

and the function in views.py.

```
def ADD_item(request, id_itm, id_itm2):
    print(id_itm, id_itm2 )
    return redirect('Invoices')
```

what I missed here to work correctly plseae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a path with two (or more) parameters with:

```
path('Up_Items/<int:id_itm>/<int:id_itm2>/', views.ADD_item, name='Up_Items'),
```

we thus define two variables `id_itm` and `id_itm2`, and both have `<int:…>` as path converter. We use a slash between the two to make it clear where one id stops and the other starts. You can also work with a comma for example, but a slash is more common and a comma should require [percent-encoding [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

then we can define a function with:

```
def ADD_item(request, id_itm, id_itm2):
    # …
    pass
```

and refer to it with:

```
<a href="{% url 'Up_Items' item.id object.id %}">
```